# how move camera up without tilting in three js

Tags: three.js

I would like to pan the camera up when the render starts. In the [official documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene), in order to move away from the placed cube, we adjust the z axis

```
camera.position.z = 5
```

Now, I want to pan up just like when I drag with the right click using orbit controls. But the result is that the camera tilts down. I'm using

```
camera.position.y = 5
```

To better understand the situation here are some references loooking at the scene from de side:

This is the initial set up

[image: This is the initial set up]

this is when I set `camera.position.z = 5`

[image: this is after setting camera.position.z = 5]

This is when I set `camera.position.y = 5` (not what I had in mind)

[image: This is when I set camera.position.y = 5]

This is what I want

[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `OrbitControls`, the camera always looks at a target point. The default value of this target is `(0, 0, 0)`. If you want to lift the camera and still want a straight look direction, you also have to adjust this target vector:

```js
controls.target.y = camera.position.y;
controls.update(); // might be necessary to update the controls
```

`three.js r116`

Comment: how to do this if im not using `OrbitControls`?

Comment: When not using `OrbitControls` you can just translate the camera. The orientation is not automatically changed.

Comment: hm i tried translating the camera but didnt have any affect. maybe something in my code conflicting? i just centered the actual blender model which was the issue for me anyways

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question for this or post at topic at the [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/).

Comment: now its working, but i have created a new question for something else. can you take a look at [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76909252/measure-from-model-to-frustrum-edge-to-adjust-camera)?